# Grab xml value using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I want to grab UPC value from the following XML example node, but the current `doc.SelectNodes` fails to grab that value. I am using `XmlDocument` to process my XML. Can you fix my code to grab UPC value? What am I doing wrong here?

C# Code:

```
string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
responseStream.Flush();
responseStream.Close();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(responseStr);
if (doc.GetElementsByTagName("Ack").Item(0).InnerText != "Failure")
{
    string UPC = doc.SelectNodes("Item").Item(0).SelectNodes("UPC").Item(0).InnerText;
}
```

XML Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2018-07-28T08:18:10.048Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Version>1069</Version>
<Build>E1069_CORE_API_18748854_R1</Build>
<Item>
    <ProductListingDetails>
        <ISBN>Not Applicable</ISBN>
        <UPC>853365007036</UPC>
        <EAN>0853365007036</EAN>
        <BrandMPN>
        <Brand>UpCart</Brand>
        <MPN>MPCB-1DX</MPN>
        </BrandMPN>
        <IncludeeBayProductDetails>true</IncludeeBayProductDetails>
    </ProductListingDetails>
</Item>
</GetItemResponse>
```

Comment: Are you able to select any other value? I mean from some another node?

Comment: No it says things i am selecting is not available.

Comment: You need to specify the correct namespace, which is `urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents`, in your call to `SelectNodes()`.  See e.g. [XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode and xmlNamespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4171451/3744182) and [Can't get XmlDocument.SelectNodes to retrieve any of my nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12607895/3744182) and [XPath with XmlDocument not finding nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40580835/3744182).

Comment: All of the above is true. Also the answer below. But why do you use `SelectNodes` and not `GetElementsByTagName` like you did with `"Ack"`?

Answer (score 0):

You have a namespace that must be used to get values.  Here is the easy way using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string UPC = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you have nulls use this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            var upcs = doc.Descendants(ns + "UPC");
            if (upcs != null)
            {
                string upc = (string)upcs.FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `doc` does not contains a definition for `Root`

Comment: You are using XmlDocument which is old.  I'm using XDocument which is the new msdn library.  Look at the header in my code.

Comment: Ok but you will see in my code i also used a `if` condition. How can i convert this to your XDoc version then? if(doc.GetElementsByTagName("Ack").Item(0).InnerText != "Failure"){}